# Set user attribute after project creation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In my app A User can create a project by giving it a name.

That is my model :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

that is my views:

```
class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['name']
    template_name = 'project_form.html'
```

How can I set when a user create a project project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True) with his ID and save it in the DB ??

Thx you

Comment: with a custom `save` method

Comment: Better, by overriding `form_valid` on the view, which is specifically covered in the [editing views documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user).

Comment: Thx Daniel It works perfectly.. could you please if you can explain me this line super(AuthorCreate, self).form_valid(form), or another doc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['name']
    template_name = 'project_form.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.project_hr_admin = self.request.user
        return super(ProjectCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

or you can also rewrite `form_valid` function as

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.project_hr_admin = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('YOUR_SUCCESS_URL')
```

Source: [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)

Comment: Hi kartikmaji thx for your answer, I used the doc provided by Daniel Roseman but I am sure yours work as well :)

Comment: @Ben2pop No issues. Happy to help. :) I have edited the answer. Let me know if another way works for you.